# How to escape strings for terminal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping, command-line-interface

I am attempting to start mplayer. My filename contains spaces and these should be escaped. 
This is the code I am using:

```
@player_pid = fork do
   exec "/usr/bin/mplayer #{song.file}"
end
```

where `#{song.file}` contains a path like `"/home/example/music/01 - a song.mp3"`. How can I escape this variable properly  (and possible other weird characters that the title may contain) so the terminal will accept my command?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Shellwords](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) should work for you :)

```
exec "/usr/bin/mplayer %s" % Shellwords.escape(song.file)
```

---

In ruby 1.9.x, it looks like you have to `require` it first

```
require "shellwords"
```

But in ruby 2.0.x, I didn't have to explicitly require it.

Answer (score 22):

Please never use the "single command line" form of `exec`, that leaves you open to all the usual quoting and injection issues and pointlessly launches a shell. From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-exec):

> **exec(cmdname, arg1, ...)**
>
> command name and one or more arguments (no shell)

So instead of mucking around with quoting and escaping and what not, just use the shell-less version:

```
exec '/usr/bin/mplayer', song.file
```

and bypass the shell completely. Similarly for [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system).

Comment: The difficulty here is going to be not everyone has the `/usr/bin/mplayer` path, so you may need to refer to a mechanism to locate the executable.  Of course, if this program is only for your consumption, it should be fine.

Comment: This solution works too indeed, but since my question actually was about how to escape a string I'm going to leave my answer unchanged, thanks though.

Comment: Yes, but when you specify the path, you lose that benefit, which is how your example is formed.  Which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: For what it's worth, "/usr/bin/env mplayer" is the standard way to find run a binary from `$PATH`.