# Is it dangerous to use a param passed by the user as a part of the shell command executed on the server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, raspberry-pi

I have a rails app with an interface like this:

```
<%= form_tag 'sound/speak', remote: true do %>
  <input type='text' name='phrase'>
  <%= submit_tag 'Say' %>
<% end %>
```

Which sends a request to a controller:

```
  def speak
    `espeak "#{params['phrase']}"`
  end
```

It works but is this a bad idea in terms of safety? I'm just trying to make my server (raspberry pi) to speak whatever I write into the textbox. However in future this might be used by a group of friends. In this case I need to make sure it's impossible to, say, escape the quotes and the "say" command and execute a malicious script/command on the server.  So, am I safe with this code?

Comment: Hmm. `[ yo"; rm -rf /; echo "  ]` comes to mind. C-;

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use [`Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) or the multi-argument form of [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system). Don't waste time and effort quoting your way through the shell when you don't really need the shell at all.

Comment: @muistooshort could you elaborate how the two are different? Are you saying that the way I have it in my example needlessly launches the shell and `Kernel#system` doesn't?

Comment: Backticks and `system(cmd)` launch a shell to parse the command line (which you just built), then the shell executes the command. Using `Open3` or `system(cmd, arg1, arg2, ...)` execute the command directly without involving a shell at all. The shell is where all the quoting problems come in so not involving a shell is a convenient way to cut out a whole class of errors and vulnerabilities.

Comment: @muistooshort awesome, thanks for clarifying, would be great if you could write an answer with basically that ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is dangerous. Consider things like this:

```
danger = 'antisocial tendencies" $(ls) "'
`echo "#{danger}"`
```

and think about what else you could do besides running `ls`.

You could use `Shellwords` (as in [**How to escape strings for terminal in Ruby?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17476389/479863)) but that would mean doing this:

1. Use `Shellwords` to escape `params['phrase']`.
2. Use string interpolation to build a command line.
3. Hand that command line to the backticks.
4. Execute a shell.
5. Let the shell parse the command line you just built.
6. Get the shell to run `espeak` with the desired argument.

You could avoid that by using the tools in [`Open3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html) or the multi-argument form of [`Kernel#system`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) to jump directly to step **(6)** without involving a shell at all.

The shell is where the quoting problems come in so not involving a shell is a convenient way to cut out a whole class of errors and vulnerabilities. Avoiding the shell is also more efficient (although you'd be hard pressed to notice) and flexible as a bonus.

---

Thanks to [sakurashinken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1887370/sakurashinken) for finding the sort-of-duplicate I linked to above, shame you deleted your answer.